# Where's the best place to get my hands on Windows XP Professional SP2/3?

Tags: windows-xp, license

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Aquire Windows XP License Keys Legally](https://superuser.com/questions/10295/aquire-windows-xp-license-keys-legally)

I require a couple of copies of Windows XP Professional and am wondering what's the best way to get these and where from?

Comment: If you were in North America I would suggest Kijiji or eBay Classified, but I don't know of any Dubai counterpart, however I am sure there should be some sort of **online classifieds**. Failing that, eBay should be of use.

Answer (score 1):

[NewEgg](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16832116515) carries XP for decent prices (looks like $135 right now).

Comment: "This item is currently out of stock and it may or may not be restocked."

Answer (score 0):

Newegg is an excellent source, but if you happen to live near a CompUSA they usually carry OEM versions for about the same price (within $5 in my experience, negligible since you needn't ship and get it same-day) as Newegg carries.